# in magento2 how to get data from loaded model by attribute?

Tags: magento2

Trying to load model by name from a category factory:

```
    $categoryModel = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
    $categoryModel->loadByAttribute('name', 'Other');
    return $categoryModel->toArray(); // this is empty for some reason
```

I debugged that in resource model, collection query is crafted properly, but why i can't make `getData` on `$categoryModel`?

The `categoryModel` is `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Interceptor` instance, and `_data` property for some reason is empty, how cat i obtain data from loaded model ?

**PS**

When I try to load it with `load($categoryId)` I am not able to make `getData()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution was to pass return variable:

`$categoryModel = $categoryModel->loadByAttribute('name', 'Other');`

and then

`$data = $categoryModel->getData()`